# Auto generation of comments for getters and setters in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, comments, getter-setter

Eclipse have an option of generating getters and setters from respective variables. Is there an option or settings by which I can also generate the comments for getters and setters?

e.g. If my variable name is

```
protected boolean isActive;
```

Then while I generate getter for this, can I also get the auto generated comment block like this -

```
/**
 * Gets the value of the isActive property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link Boolean }
 *     
 */
public Boolean getIsActive() {
    return isActive;
}
```

Would be great if this thing is possible. Also is that comment block customizable?

Comment: While it might be possible to make this work by modifying the default template through Preferences, don't you this this a overkill as the comments for getters would not add any value except in few scenarios?

Comment: Ya right. But you can't help it when customer is a fool to understand that. ;)

Comment: Or you can go with http://projectlombok.org/ : no more comment to generate ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Preferences>Java>Code Style>Code Templates and then change the Comments>Getters template.  You also want to make sure the 'Automatically add comments for new methods and types' checkbox is selected.